# Reading a file with headers and comments textscan

Tags: matlab, input

I have a file that looks like this:

```
(floor 12)
(          x           y            z            u            v            w     diameter            t    mass-flow         mass    frequency         time         name)
(( 4.0331e-01   0.0000e+00   1.3201e+00  -3.1926e-03  -2.9862e-02   2.5690e-02   2.5000e-06   3.0000e+02   0.0000e+00   8.1665e-15   0.0000e+00   5.8257e+02) injection-0:8)
```

I'd just like the x y z values. I'm using textscan unsuccessfully but am open to suggestions:

```
[x y z] = textscan (fid, '%n %n %f %f %f %*[^\n]', 'HeaderLines', 2);
```

I'm not sure how to treat `((` . What are the options?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if it's always `((` then the following should work, it will put your 3 values into a cell, hence the myCell{1} to allocate the values if you need them in a seperate variables.

```
myCell = textscan (fid, '(( %f %f %f %*[^\n]', 'HeaderLines', 2);
x=myCell{1};
y=myCell{2};
z=myCell{3};
```

Comment: Works a treat!  Thank you! Now I no longer have to strip out all my files!  so now x, y and z are cells.  I still can't get my head around why some functions needs cells and others vectors.  Is there a general way to know which require which? Regards,

Comment: I'm not aware of any general way - you just have to read the documentation, e.g. from textscan it says "The number of specifiers determines the number of cells in the cell array C."

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `fgets()` twice before you call `textscan()` to skip the headers.